# Hadoop error when writing on hdfs using maven for java program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have setup hadoop standalone cluster. I am trying to run a hadoop mapreduce program using apache maven. i have included following library hadoop-client-2.0.0-cdh4.5.0 , hadoop-core-1.2.1 too. When running on local filesystem everything is ok. but when i try to write on hdfs it is giving me following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration

Regards,
Bhavesh gadoya.

Answer (score 1):

```
add   commons-configuration-1.6.jar jar or maven dependency

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

refer:
[How can i make a new directory in hdfs with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832109/how-can-i-make-a-new-directory-in-hdfs-with-java/28833584#28833584)

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-3-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_31.html

Comment: Now i got the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta

Comment: Thanks sravan for your answer ... Yes i got the hint from your reference. I have added a wrong jar file .. adding hadoop-mapreduce-client-core & hadoop-client solve my problem